# Cycle classes that are killed by pushing forward from normalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a non-normal algebraic variety and $f \colon X' \to X$ its normalization. Is there a general description $\mathrm{ker}\left(\mathrm{CH}_k(X') \to \mathrm{CH}_k(X)\right)$? Are there hypotheses that ensure that it is generated by cycles $[Z]$ such that $\dim f(Z) < \dim Z$, and differences $[Z]-[W]$ where $f(Z)=f(W)$?

Comment: There are no cycles $Z$ such that $\text{dim} f(Z)$ is strictly less than $\text{dim}(Z)$, since $f$ is finite.  I believe there are examples where the kernel is not generated only by $[Z]-[W]$ with $f(Z)=f(W)$.  I will try to come up with a specific example.

Comment: I think this gives a counterexample.  I am posting as a comment, because it does not address the actual question: "hypotheses that ensure it *is* generated by ...".  Let $C$ be a very general hyperelliptic curve of genus $g>1$.  Let $i:C\to C$ be the hyperelliptic involution.  Let $f:C\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the quotient.  Let $Y'$ be $C\times C$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ acting via $(i,\text{Id})$ and $(\text{Id},i)$.  Let $g:Y'\to Y$ be the quotient, $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.  Let $X'$ be $\mathbb{P}^1\times Y'$, and let $f:X'\to X$ contract $\{0\}\times Y'$ to $Y$.

Comment: (cont.) Now consider $1$-cycles in $X'$.  The kernel will basically be the kernel of the pushforward map of $1$-cycles $g_*:\text{CH}_1(Y')\to \text{CH}_1(Y)$.  If $g(Z)$ equals $g(W)$, then $W$ is a translate of $Z$ by an element $g$ in the group.  Thus $[W]-[Z]$ is $g^*[Z]-[Z]$.  If the kernel was generated by such elements, the same would be true after passing to numerical equivalence classes.  But I believe this already fails there.  The group of numerical equivalence classes is generated by the two fibers, $[F_1]$ and $[F_2]$, the diagonal $[\Delta]$, and the graph of $i$, $[\Delta']$.

Comment: (cont. 2)  Now $[F_1]$ and $[F_2]$ are invariant under the group action, and $[\Delta]$ is permuted with $[\Delta']$.  So every class $[W]-[Z]$ is numerically equivalent to a multiple of $[\Delta]-[\Delta']$.  Unfortunately, the quotient of the numerical group by this cyclic subgroup has rank $3$, whereas the rankof the numerical group of $Y=\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is only $2$.  So the kernel does contain more elements, e.g., $[\Delta]-[F_1]-[F_2]$.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks a lot! I will try to understand your example.

Comment: @Jason: I tried computing $\mathrm{CH}_1^{\mathrm{num}}(Y')$ in your example and it seems to me that $[\Delta]+[\Delta']$ is numerically equivalent to $2[F_1] + 2[F_2]$. So I don't think it has rank four.

Comment: I think that you are correct.  Perhaps the example can be salvaged if $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve admitting correspondences "without valence", i.e., if there are "extra" numerical equivalence classes.  I will see if I can fix this.

Comment: I can probably prove that any element of this kernel is the image of an element of $CH_k(X'\times_X X')$ via $p_{1*}-p_{2*}$ where $p_i$ are the projections. Should I write this down?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Thanks, that's nice! The application I had in mind for this result was a bit half-baked, so I'm sorry to say that I don't personally need this written down. I can't really judge how interesting it is on its own.